# What does it mean to "fight through the pain"?

Tags: diablo-iii

[The Burning Axe of Sankis](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-burning-axe-of-sankis) says:

> Chance to fight through the pain when enemies hit you.

What does this do?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it casts Ignore Pain, which is a barb ability for damage reduction, but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It casts ["Ignore Pain"](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/ignore-pain) on you, causing you to take 50 percent damage for 5 seconds.

[Source](http://www.diablohub.com/database/item/the-burning-axe-of-sankis/information/)

According to a [great post](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5967129011#8) by muir who analyzed the effects of the weapon, it essentially prevents 28.2 percent of all damage taken (at least while in the thick of it), once you account for procs.

Comment: So, it would stack with [Pride of Cassius](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/pride-of-cassius)?

Comment: It seems like that would be the case.

Comment: do you know what the proc chance is?